# I'd like to get drivers for wifi on hp

Tags: 14.04, drivers, wireless, hp

I found an answer to my question on how to get drivers for ubuntu 14 to get my wifi going but where do you enter this code?

```
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: the last part of this assumes that I know too much.

Comment: do you want me to put in another cd to write to? and then boot off of the cd?

Answer (score 1):

You should enter the code in the terminal. Open the terminal with Ctrl+Alt+t. Next, type:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Press Enter. You will be asked for your password. Simply type it in and press Enter. For security reasons, it will not be echoed back, not even ****. Next:

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

Press Enter. Next:

```
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
```

Press Enter for this and after each subsequent command. Next:

```
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot.

Comment: Using -b extended in the git clone command will add support for the rtl8823be and possibly the rtl8723de chipsets